# Why does Konata call Kagami Kagamin?

Tags: lucky-star

Every now and then, Konata calls Kagami **Kagamin**. Why? Does this change the meaning of the name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just a suffix that makes the name a little more cute, it's roughly the same as having a friend called, I don't know, Sam, and calling him "Sammy".

It is also similar to adding "-chan" to the name. I guess Konata does that partly to annoy Kagami a little.

In case you're wondering, the name Kagami means "mirror".

Comment: Thanks :) Are you aware of other examples beside Kagamin? Could, say, _Hikari_ become _Hikarin_? (There's actually an episode where Tsukasa offers _Kyou-chan_ as a nickname for her sister. Kagami doesn't like it and asks Kona-chan to call her Kagami-sama instead.)

Comment: As far as I know, one kanji character read as `Kyou` means `demon`.

Comment: Tsukasa suggests Kyou since it can also mean _mirror_. Konata agrees with her on _Kyou_ since it can mean both _powerful_, and with a minor change, _evil_.

Comment: @coleopterist, yea, though "Kagami-sama" didn't last long after Konata actually started calling her so :P As for other examples, unfortunately I don't know. I guess it might be different for every specific name, since some names probably _can_ change their meaning if you add -n to them. I'm not sure though.

Comment: @coleopterist for another example Akari in Yuruyuri is occasionally interchanged with Akarin.

Comment: Late to this party, but IIRC, Hiyori Tamura is called Hiyorin by Konata. As one more example, in Ro Kyu Bu, Maho forms several nicknames by adding *-n* (Tomoka becomes Mokkan, Airi becomes Airin, Subaru becomes Subarun, etc.)

Comment: @coleopterist, in Azumanga Daioh. Kimura sensei calls himself Kimurin. He also calls Kaori Kaorin.

Comment: In KareKano: Yukino -> Yukinon